# What is the difference between fork() with else and without else

Tags: c, linux, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(){
    if(fork()>0){
        printf("i am p\n");
        fork();
    }    
    else{
        printf("i am c\n");
    }
}
```

the output is

```
i am p
i am c
```

without else the output is

```
i am p
i am c
i am c
i am c
```

I can't understand the second fork do when with else and without else.

Comment: Please read the fork man page.  
https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

Comment: The one without the else is lying.

Answer (score 3):

The parent process forks a new process, since fork return value is 0 in child process, it skips the if and will print `i am c`. The parent process will print `i am p` and will fork again! The second child and the parent will now print `i am c` 3 times this was printed. If you keep the `else` the parent and second child were running inside the `if` won't execute the `else` block obviously.